# Joining data frames with recurring variable

Tags: r, dplyr, inner-join

The problem I'm having is that `inner_join()` creates a new row with all the associated values.

An example:

```
zip_code <- c("1000", "1000", "1001")
village <- c("village_x", "village_y", "village_z")
villages <- data.frame(cbind(zip_code, village))

zip_code <- c("1000", "1000", "1001")
case <- c("case1", "case2", "case3")
cases <- data.frame(cbind(zip_code, case))

data <- inner_join(villages, cases, by="zip_code")
```

This solution increases the number of cases, as there are several villages with the same ZIP code.

How can I make it so that villages with the same ZIP code are in the same cell?

Or that the merge only pairs the cases with the first found value?

Comment: data <- inner_join(villages, cases, by="zip_code") %>%
        group_by(zip_code, case) %>% 
        summarize(village = paste(village, collapse = ', '), .groups = 'drop')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ConnerSexton's solution worked:

```
data <- inner_join(villages, cases, by="zip_code") %>% group_by(zip_code, case) %>% summarize(village = paste(village, collapse = ', '), .groups = 'drop')
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: No prob, happy to help :)